# Searching and Replacing between Two Data Frames with Apply Family

Tags: r, search, for-loop, replace, apply

I'm trying to analyze a large set of data so I can't use for loops to search for ID's from one data frame on the other and replace the text.

Basically, first data frame is with IDs and without names. The names are in the other data frame.

**(Edit)** Input dfs

**(Edit)** df1

```
ID------Name
1,2,3---NA
4,5-----NA
6-------NA
```

**(Edit)** df2

```
ID------Name
1-------John
2-------John
3-------John
4-------Stacy
5-------Stacy
6-------Alice
```

**(Edit)** Expected output df

```
ID------Name
1,2,3---John
4,5-----Stacy
6-------Alice
```

**(Edit)** Please note that this is very simplified version. df1 actually has 63 columns and 8551 rows, df2 has 5 columns and 37291 rows.

I can search for the IDs and get names on the second data frame like this. It' super fast!

```
namer <- function(df2, ids) {
  ids <- gsub(',', '|', ids);
  names <- df2[which(apply(df2, 1, function(x) any(grepl(ids, x)))),][['Name']];
  if (length(names) != 0) {
    return(names[[1]]);
  } else {
    return(NA);
  }
}
```

But, I can't replace using apply families. I know doing it with for loops and it's super slow because I have around 8500 rows in the first data frame.

```
for (k in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  df1$Name[k] <- namer(df2, df1$ID[k]);
}
```

Can you please help to do convert for loops into apply functions as well to speed it up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected output? Please clarify input df and output df?

Comment: I added expected output and input dfs please look at them them with (Edit) markers. @Andreas I guess I cannot merge them because they're not similar in rows because df1 has multiple IDs in its ID column. But it did for the searching part. I was doing it with for loop as well and looked at the Internet and found out this way.

Comment: @Gungor, May be I misunderstood, but can't you use `aggregate(ID~., df2, I)`

Comment: @akrun So what it does to get rid of same IDs and obtain singles. This wasn't really the thing I want here but I guess I'm gonna this this kind of fuction to count how many unique names present in the data. So thanks, it'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df1$Name <- sapply(as.character(df1$ID), 
       function(x) paste(unique(df2[match(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]], df2$ID), "Name"]), collapse = ","))
df1
#      ID  Name
# 1 1,2,3  John
# 2   4,5 Stacy
# 3     6 Alice
```

Although I doubt `sapply` will be faster than a `for` loop. I've also added `paste` function here in case you have more than one name matched in `df1$ID`

Comment: Believe me this is much faster than for loop, it resulted in no time. Yes, I realized you are pasting possible extra names, I guess I don't have any but good to analyze it like this. This worked as expected. Thanks a lot!